# I'm Receiving an error of failed to fetch when trying to fetch data from a recipe api. how can I fix this issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to make a fetch request to a recipe API but am receiving this error and have no idea how to fix it

> TypeError: Failed to fetch

Locally the request works fine, however now I've uploaded my application to netlify I've had this issue.

The code for my request is as follows

```
const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_EDAMAM_API_KEY;
const APP_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_EDAMAM_APP_ID;
const url = `https://api.edamam.com/search?app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${API_KEY}&q=`;

const fetchMyApi = async (searchQuery) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url + searchQuery);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data.hits;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  return [];
};

export default fetchMyApi;
```

I have no idea how to fix this issue.